# Updating state using dynamic props json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which receives a json object in props from parent component and the API call to populate json object is made in parent component only.

My problem is how can do I define state in child component to hold values of json object prop. I am storing json object in child as state because it's a update or cancel update situation in child component so I basically states like - `dataCopy`, `dataOriginal`, and on cancel update I try to change `dataCopy` to `dataOriginal` and reverse on update save operation.

I am stuck as values from props are copied as reference and also since json object might be dynamic so if I do `dataCopy.some1.some2 = something` then it's not possible as inside state I define data as `dataCopy:{}, dataOriginal:{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `componentDidUpdate()` but be very careful in using this.

Please read --> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: what about dynamic prop structure as state variable is like `dataCopy:{}` but I need to update like `dataCopy.some1.some2 = something`.

Comment: When componentDidUpdate() happens, it means that there was a change either to state or props. You can make the verification at that moment, and from there update whatever you think you need to update.

Comment: I can't do `dataCopy.some1.some2 = something` as in state it was defined as `dataCopy:{}`

Comment: You can do a `this.setState({dataCopy:whateverObjectOrValue})`

Comment: I need to update nested child key which is not possible through `setStte`

Answer (score 0):

Try using spread operator `...object` while setting dynamic props object to your state.

`this.setState({dataCopy:{...this.props.object}})`

This might be helpful https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eb6fpb